# Admin Account for Domain could not be created

Tags: google-app-engine

just purchased a new domain @ blogger and i can't create my admin account for my domain on Google App Engine for creating my free 1 account only admin login. It's been two days since my purchase and the server is still down. Could anyone help me with that?
The error message is shown:

Google Apps Server Error
Try again later.

Comment: I hope that you have created an admin email, while you were signing up for Google Apps so you should use that for logging in.

Answer (score 2):

Since Google automatically created a new admin account for you, thus, you just need to sign in with bloggeradmin as your username and use the same password as you use for your blog.Here the answer for you in details.

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/apps/7kC61VTXIPk/119XuuYXh2AJ